# Change image without page refresh or reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, image

I am using this guide.

http://jsfiddle.net/nz8qy41y/

Problem:
**When I click on [1] [2] or [3] main image is not changing. Instead I am redirected to image.**

View.
Main image:

```
<div class="block-2-image"> 

<a href=<%=@advertisement.pictures.first.image.url(:original)%> data-lightbox="gallery"><%=  image_tag @advertisement.pictures.first.image.url(:medium),
    :title=> @advertisement.name,:id=>"main-image", :alt =>                                   @advertisement.name%></a>

</div>
```

Thumbnail images:

```
<ul class="thumbnail">
    <% @advertisement.pictures.to_enum.with_index(1) do |thumb, index|%>


         <li><a href=<%=thumb.image.url(:medium)%>><%= index %></a></li>


    <% end %> 
</ul>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.thumbnail li').on('click',function(){
      $('.block-2-image a').find('img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
   });
});
```

**Now when I click on small images it links to right image, but in other view.
I need to change image in the same view.**

Any help ?

Thanks.

Comment: `Maybe just change image path when click to those number images happen?` Ya try it

Comment: Something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nz8qy41y/)

Comment: @BogdanKuštan Tnx. But my code won't change main image, it just redirects to right image paths. Something with the script ?

Comment: @EdgarsRozenfelds in `click` callback function You should pass `event` parameter (variable `e` in my example) and inside function call `event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake.

I had duplicate script code inside Application.js that mixed up everything.

Answer (score 1):

include jquery if it not included
in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.thumbnail li img').on('click',function(){
      $('.block-2-image').find('img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
   });
});
```

but with that way its better to type a full path for your images in html

Answer (score 1):

Pure JS variation of @Mohamed's answer (not tested):

```
window.onload = function() {
    var selector = document.querySelector(".thumbnail li img");
    selector.addEventListener("click", function() {
        var img = document.querySelector(".block-2-image img");
        img.setAttribute("src", selector.getAttribute("src"));
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. but idea is to avoid having small - thumbnails in that selection. I have for diferent images that represent image number not thumbnail.

Comment: I'm sorry could you rephrase that? I am still missing what I'm missing.

Comment: @eatonphill  Your code changes main image to thumbnail, but I don't need that. I need ability to click one of four small images and then change main image from other path.

Comment: What do you mean by "change main image from other path"?

Comment: I am trying to change main image from clicks on small images, but those small images are not thumbnails. They just represent count of aviable images .

Comment: I'm really not sure. Though it appears that whatever your question now is, it is beyond the scope of the original question. If I am beginning to understand you correctly, either of our answers should give you what you need. If you need to operate on the src string first, then do so. But I am having trouble understanding exactly what you need.