# Change image and its source with clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745060/change-image-without-page-refresh-or-reload) question I created ability to click to `[1][2][3][4]` to change main image.

Now It works great. Main image changes as expected. But when I click to main image to get pop up it just shows up default image or I could say first one.

**Issue**: *For better explanation: I can see some image, but when I click on that pop-up shows other one.!*

Main image view:

```
div class="block-2-image">                                  
                            
    <a href=<%=@advertisement.pictures.first.image.url(:original)%> data-lightbox="gallery"><%=  image_tag @advertisement.pictures.first.image.url(:medium),
                              :title=> @advertisement.name,:id=>"main-image", :alt =>                                   @advertisement.name%></a>
</div>
```

Image numbers as `[1][2][3][4]`

```
<ul class="thumbnail">
        <% @advertisement.pictures.to_enum.with_index(1) do |thumb, index|%>
                            

      <li><a href=<%=thumb.image.url(:medium)%> class="inactiver"><%= index %></a></li>
                                        
    <% end %> 
</ul>
```

My script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.thumbnail a').on('click', function(e){
      $('.block-2-image img').attr('src', $(this).attr('href')); //nomaina bildi, bet klikskinot paliek vecais bildes links
    
    e.preventDefault();
     var sidebar = $('.thumbnail');
    sidebar.delegate('a.inactiver','click',function(){
        sidebar.find('.activer').toggleClass('activer inactiver');
        $(this).toggleClass('activer inactiver');
    });
    // $(this).css('border-width', '2');
 
});

});
```

But that code changes image source ? Why then it is for other image ?

Thanks

Comment: This might be because you have multiple occurrence of ".block-2-image img" in a page. If so try changing source attribute relatively using parent > child

Comment: @shahmanthan9 Thanks. I don't have multpiple ".block-2-image img " in page. Maybe the problem is caused by lightbox that is handling image pop up ?